# Actionscript 2: Add all entries in an xml file to an array

Tags: xml, arrays, while-loop, actionscript-2

I have an xml file that has 3075 entries that look something like this

```
<item id="1" itype="COLOUR"></item>
```

I'm using action script 2 to load the xml and then a while loop the enter all data into an array using this code.

```
my_xml = new XML();
paper_crumbs = Array();
my_xml.load("sample.xml");
my_xml.onLoad = my_function;
my_xml.ignoreWhite = 1;

function my_function() {
var b = true;
var num = "1";
while(b == true){
paper_crumbs[my_xml.firstChild.childNodes[num].attributes.id] = {type: my_xml.firstChild.childNodes[num].attributes.itype, cost: 0, is_member: false}; 
if(my_xml.firstChild.childNodes[num].attributes.final == "yes"){
b = false;
trace("done");
}
num = num + 1;
}
}
```

The problem i am having is that it makes flash unresponsive then asks if i would like to terminate the script, is there any other way i can loop through the xml and add them to an array or could someone edit the while so it works?

Comment: I know it's been a while, but wanted top know if my answer resolved your issue.  Just curious, thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

Some of syntax of your code is incorrect and I updated your XML format to make it easier to process and put it into an easier format to tweak later.  I've created a sample shown below with code that properly loops over each entry in my sample.xml file.

**sample.xml:**

```
<items>
    <item id="1" itype="COLOUR"></item>
    <item id="2" itype="COLOUR"></item>
    <item id="3" itype="COLOUR"></item>
    <item id="4" itype="COLOUR"></item>
    <item id="5" itype="COLOUR"></item>
    <item id="6" itype="COLOUR"></item>
    <item id="7" itype="COLOUR"></item>
    <item id="8" itype="COLOUR"></item>
    <item id="9" itype="COLOUR"></item>
    <item id="10" itype="COLOUR"></item>
    <item id="11" itype="COLOUR"></item>
    <item id="12" itype="COLOUR"></item>
    <item id="13" itype="COLOUR"></item>
    <item id="14" itype="COLOUR"></item>
    <item id="15" itype="COLOUR"></item>
    <item id="16" itype="COLOUR"></item>
    <item id="17" itype="COLOUR"></item>
    <item id="18" itype="COLOUR"></item>
    <item id="19" itype="COLOUR"></item>
    <item id="20" itype="COLOUR"></item>
</items>
```

**ActionScript:**

```
my_xml = new XML();
paper_crumbs = Array();
my_xml.load("sample.xml");
my_xml.onLoad = my_function;
my_xml.ignoreWhite = true;

function my_function() {

    var rootNode:XMLNode = my_xml.firstChild;   // <items> node
    var itemNode:XMLNode = rootNode.firstChild; // get first child from <items>
    var xmlNodeID:Number;
    var xmlNodeType:String;

    while(itemNode != null){

        xmlNodeID = itemNode.attributes.id;
        xmlNodeType = itemNode.attributes.itype;

        paper_crumbs.push( {id: xmlNodeType, type: xmlNodeType, cost: 0, is_member: false} );

        itemNode = itemNode.nextSibling;

    } // end while

} // end function
```